# Date and Cause of death numbers on New York Passenger list?

Tags: united-states, immigration, cause-of-death

I am trying to find out the date and cause of death of a passenger in the [New York, Passenger and Crew Lists (including Castle Garden and Ellis Island), 1820-1957](https://www.ancestry.com/sharing/17912367?h=e04aef&utm_campaign=bandido-webparts&utm_source=post-share-modal&utm_medium=copy-url) on Ancestry.

The passenger is Maria Wertz (age 26) on the passenger list for the ship *New York*, sailing from Southampton, arriving in the port of New York on 22 Jan 1894 (from NARA's M237, Roll 622).  Her entry is on line number 9.

It looks as though she was a governess and the code under Date and cause of death is 2 - 1?

What would have happened to her body?

Comment: Need more information... can you provide a link to the record?

Comment: HER NAME IS MARIA WERTZ 
 #9              https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/7488/NYM237_622-0430/4019155142?backurl=https://www.ancestry.com/family-tree/person/tree/12453695/person/26660604828/facts/citation/602186028564/edit/record

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Your question is similar to one we already have -- see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2182/1006.  I have added a shareable link for the image to your question. The link you posted in the comments includes the backURL to someone's tree -- did you intend to include that? That profile has a history for Maria Wertz after her arrival in the USA -- have you checked that research?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think those numbers refer to deaths.  I believe they are related to later compilation of statistics, and the statisticians used the blank space in that column for their notes.  Recording of a death would include a date.
The example had many people on that page with such numbers.  If they really all died on a voyage in 1894 you'd likely find some reporting in the New York newspapers.